# track closest values in a table Shiny r

Tags: r, shiny, dt, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity

I am building a Shiny App that does random simulations of some stuff in three ways and saves the results in a table. I want the table to (1) fill the cell green for the closest value to the correct answer, and (2) include a line on bottom tracking total number of times each test group has been the closest.

what I have:
[image]

what I want:
[image]

Here's the code I'm using:
By the way, in this example there are ties, but that won't really be possible in the real thing, so probably not necessary to deal with.

```
#
# This is a Shiny web application. You can run the application by clicking
# the 'Run App' button above.
#
# Find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
#
#    http://shiny.rstudio.com/
#

library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("test"),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            actionButton("random_select",
                         "Generate Random Numbers",
                         width = 'auto')
        ),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
           tableOutput("results_table_output")
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

    counter <- reactiveValues(countervalue = 0)
    
    observeEvent(input$random_select,{
        counter$countervalue = counter$countervalue + 1
    }
    )

    
    results <- reactiveValues(
        table = list(trial = NA,
                     answer =NA,
                     test_1 = NA,
                     test_2 = NA,
                     test_3 = NA)
    )
    
    observeEvent(counter$countervalue,{
        results$table$trial[counter$countervalue] <- as.integer(counter$countervalue)
        results$table$answer[counter$countervalue] <- sample(1:10,1)
        results$table$test_1[counter$countervalue] <- sample(1:10,1)
        results$table$test_2[counter$countervalue] <- sample(1:10,1)
        results$table$test_3[counter$countervalue] <- sample(1:10,1)
                
    })
    
    output$results_table_output <- renderTable({
        results$table
    })
    
    
    }

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: You could maybe use the package [`DT`](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/010-style.html) to style the cells

Answer (score 0):

### Disclaimer

I would also fall back to a more advanced table rendering engine like `DT`. However, in the following I show another solution which works with `renderTable` from "base" `shiny`.

---

### `renderTable` + `JS` Solution

If you don't mind using some `JavaScript` you can use the following snippet:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
js <- HTML("function mark_cells() {
   $('.mark-cell').parent('td').css('background-color', 'steelblue');
}

function add_totals() {
   const ncols = $('table th').length;
   const $col_totals = Array(ncols).fill().map(function(el, idx) {
      const $cell = $('<td></td>');
      if (idx == 1) {
         $cell.text('total:');
      } else if (idx > 1) {
         $cell.text($('table tr td:nth-child(' + (idx + 1) + ') .mark-cell').length);
      }
      return $cell;
   })
   $('table tfoot').remove();
   $('table > tbody:last-child')
      .after($('<tfoot></tfoot>').append($('<tr></tr>').append($col_totals))); 
}

function mark_table() {
   mark_cells();
   add_totals()
}
")

make_run <- function(i, answer, tests = integer(3))  {
  cn <- c("trial", "answer", paste0("test_", seq_along(tests)))
  if (is.null(i)) {
    line <- matrix(integer(0), ncol = length(cn))
    colnames(line) <- cn
  } else {
    line <- matrix(as.integer(c(i, answer, tests)), ncol = length(cn))
    colnames(line) <- cn
  }
  as.data.frame(line)
}

mark_best <- function(row) {
  truth <- row[2]
  answers <- row[-(1:2)]
  dist <- abs(answers - truth)
  best <- dist == min(dist)
  answers[best] <- paste0("<span class = \"mark-cell\">", answers[best], "</span>")
  c(row[1:2], answers)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  tags$head(tags$script(js)),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("random_select",
                   "Generate Random Numbers")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("results_table_output")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  results <- reactiveVal(make_run(NULL))
  observeEvent(input$random_select, {
    res <- results()
    results(rbind(res, make_run(nrow(res) + 1, sample(10, 1), sample(10, 3, TRUE))))
  })
  
  output$results_table_output <- renderTable({
    res <- results()
    if (nrow(res) > 0) {
      res <- as.data.frame(t(apply(res, 1, mark_best)))
      session$onFlushed(function() runjs("mark_table()"))
    }
    res
  }, sanitize.text.function = identity)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

### Explanation

- In the `renderTable` function, we call `mark_best` where we surround the "winning" cells with `<span class = "mark-cell">`. This helps us on the `JS` side to identify which cells are the winners.
- In order to **not** escape the HTML in it, we use the argument `sanitize.text.function` which is responsible for, well, sanitizing strings in the cell. Because we want to print them as is, we supply the `identity` function.
- We include 3 `JavaScript` functions in the `<head>` of the document, which

  - color the parent `<td>` of our marked cells (`mark_cells()`)
  - add column totals to the table. This is done by counting the `.mark-cell` marked cells in each column (`add_totals`)
  - a convenience wrapper to call both functions (`mark_table()`)
- In order to be able to actually call the `JS` function we rely on `shinyjs`. This is however, merely syntactic sugar and could be achieved otherwise as well (if you mind the additional library). To make `shinyjs` work, we need to include a call to `useShinyjs` in the `UI`.
- All what is left to do is to call `mark_table` in the `renderTable` function. To make sure that the table is rendered properly, we do not call the `JS` function right away but use `session$onFlushed` to register the call to be run after the next flush happens.